# GRANT with database name wildcard in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, syntax, permissions, sql-grant

I want to create a user 'projectA' that has the same permissions to every database named 'projectA_%'

I know its possible but MySQL doesn't like my syntax:

```
grant all on 'projectA\_%'.* to 'projectA'@'%';
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If I use back-tics instead of single quotes in the syntax, it appears to work just fine:

```
grant all on `projectA\_%`.* to `projectA`@`%`;
```

Comment: back-tics are only needed for the database name, not the user

Comment: This not works for me when I use `specific table name` instead of `*` e.g.     ``grant all on `projectA%`.`some_table%` to `some_user`@`%`;``

Comment: @NamGVU When specifying a table level privilege, wildcards in the DB are treated as the character _ and %. They are not wildcards anymore. See the GRANT documentation under "Object Quoting Guidelines"

Answer (score 15):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `projectA\_%`.* TO 'projectA'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_passwd';
```

back-tics are needed for the database name

Edited:Underscore is now escaped.

Answer (score 9):

As per MySQL's [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-accounts-passwords) documentation:

> The “_” and “%” wildcards are permitted when specifying database names
>   in GRANT statements that grant privileges at the global or database
>   levels. This means, for example, that if you want to use a “_”
>   character as part of a database name, you should specify it as “\_” in
>   the GRANT statement, to prevent the user from being able to access
>   additional databases matching the wildcard pattern; for example, GRANT
>   ... ON `foo\_bar`.* TO ....