# mySQL grant custom permission to different user

Tags: mysql

I tried:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON someuser_.* TO 'someuser'@'%';
```

but it allows me creating only one database **someuser_**
I want to allow user **someuser** for all the database-name starts with **someuser_** [like cPanel]

I tired:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON someuser_*.* TO 'someuser'@'%';
```

but it returns me:

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

Comment: [GRANT with database name wildcard in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2668591/6248528)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GRANT with database name wildcard in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668591/grant-with-database-name-wildcard-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. but the user cannot drop database now.