# Grant user to multiple db but only one table

Tags: mysql, database, sql-grant

I'm trying to grant access one user to many db that have been created on my system like this:

dbUser_1
dbUser_2
...

and so on.

I can use `` GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON `dbUser\_%`.* TO 'kenny'@'localhost'; ``
To let kenny user to insert, select and update ALLL the table of each db.

I'm looking for make something like this: ATENTION, this don't work:
`` GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON `dbUser\_%`.*`bill` TO 'kenny'@'localhost'; ``

To let kenny get access to all the bill tables on each db.

¿It is possible?

I'm using mysql.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON DBNAME.TABLE_NAME TO USERNAME
```

So it will be something like this:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON dbUser\_%.* TO 'kenny'@'localhost';
```

For more check:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Update:
When specifying a table level privilege, wildcards in the DB are treated as the character _ and %. They are not wildcards anymore. See the GRANT documentation under "Object Quoting Guidelines" (@mhost)

Comment: Hi Voli, this answer don't works for me because i'm looking for Grant access to all the db with the same prefix (dbUser_1, dbUser_2 ...) but only one of the tables of each database (`bill`)

When I try to Grant with wildcards, the system tell me that the "Table doesn't exist"...

I need this solution to let the future db of the sistem be updated by this user.

Thanks for your aswer.

Comment: I can only redirect you to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668591/grant-with-database-name-wildcard-in-mysql/2668660#comment100527739_2668660
Sorry that I couldn't help you with this :)