# Access denied for user when running laravel test

Tags: php, phpunit

i have a problem when i run tests in parallel mode i face this error :

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'default'@'%' to database 'shop_test_4'
```

Or

```
330) Tests\Feature\Qualification\QualificationTest::testGetLikeProviders
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'default'@'%' to database ':memory:'
```

and in my phpunit.xml i got this config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         printerClass="NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Phpunit\Printer"
>

    <extensions>
        <extension class="Tests\LongRunningTestAlert" />
    </extensions>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
         <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
<!--         <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>-->
<!--        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>-->
<!--        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>-->

        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

when i run the tests in normal way i got no problem

Comment: i have edited my question . the point on that if you read well is that the tests running in normal mode have no problem but the user cant access in database when running parallel mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you have created a MySQL user (`default`) that has permissions to access a database `shop_test`. When you run the tests normally, Laravel just uses the `shop_test` database as you'd expect and everything works. When you run in parallel mode, Laravel uses more than one database to prevent collisions. The easiest solution is just to grant your database user access to all databases that begin with the prefix `shop_test`. Since you're using MySQL, then something along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2668660/8292439) should be helpful:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON `shop_test\_%`.* TO `default`@`%`;
```

If you're using SQLite, then you should be able to just use the default config because each test instance will have its own in-memory database.